# string not recognized valid date time

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime-format, cultureinfo

input value ="3:10 PM" or "15:10" depend on regional settings in control panel.
when set to India input value is "15:10" and when set to US input value is "3:10 PM". I have to convert input value to "1899-12-30 15:10:00.000" every time for that written below code but while parsing its showing error "**String was not recognized as a valid Date Time**".

```
 Private Function GetCurrentTime(ByVal value As String) As DateTime
        Dim oaDate As DateTime
        Dim timeValue As DateTime

        oaDate = DateTime.FromOADate(0)
        value = String.Concat(oaDate.Year, oaDate.Month, oaDate.Day, value)
        timeValue = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHH:mm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Return timeValue

    End Function
```

Comment: Try this article on MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're input can be different depending on the culture then you can't use the following line to parse the string:

```
timeValue = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHH:mm", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

as you've got a single fixed format and you are specifying an invariant culture.

If the input might be invalid you should either trap the exception and display a suitable error message or use `TryParseExact` and display a suitable error message if that returns `false`.

You must either check the current culture and call either your current code or the code for the US, or test each possible format in turn using `TryParseExact` until you find one that produces a valid date. There is an overload of [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a list of format strings so you can do the check in on go. You'd need something like this (apologies for the C# syntax):

```
string[] formats = {"yyyyMMddHH:mm", "yyyyMMddh:mm"};
DateTime result
if (TryParseExact(value, formats, ..., out result))
{
    // use the result
}
else
{
    // invalid input
}
```

However, (and this is a big however), you could get the situation where the input could be valid in more than one culture you could end up with the wrong result.